# Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome and HUD

Tags: unity, gnome, hud

Now that Ubuntu is moving back to Gnome as the default desktop, will you port the HUD? It's Unity's killer feature, and I will miss it...
So please port the HUD!

Comment: This also seems like something that can be added trough an extension  because it just interacts with existing menu items in the applications.

Comment: An interesting blogpost on this on the gnome website: https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/Playground/HUD

Comment: I also found this: https://github.com/p-e-w/plotinus This is the hud for gnome and it seems like exactly what you want. It's not ready yet though.